# Which elements are affected by font hinting?

Tags: fonts

I used gnome-tweaks to change font hinting and reloaded gnome with alt F2 "t" but I couldn't determine any changes  are only some elements affected? or do I need better glasses?

Answer (score 1):

What's affected by that setting in Tweaks is the rendering on the desktop. The shell, Settings, various other GTK applications etc. It does not affect the rendering of web pages on the Internet. Neither are applications such as Firefox, Thunderbird or LibreOffice affected.